# Multiple if statemens in one Function in SML

Tags: function, if-statement, standards, sml, ml

I want to write a function in SML that checks if the parameters `a`, `b`, `c` are `true` and, if they are, increases the value `x` with `1.0`, `2.0` or `3.0`. 
For Example:

```
fun calc(a:bool, b:bool, c:bool, d:int) = 
let
    val x = 0.0
in
    if a then x+1.0 else x+0.0
    ;if b then x+2.0 else x+0.0
    ;if c then x+3.0 else x+0.0
    ;if d<120 then x+4.0 else x+0.0
end
```

If I run this code with `a`, `b` and `c` `true` and `d < 120`, then I get the output:

```
val it = 0.0 : real
```

but I want to get as output `x`.

Comment: Why not simply `if a` rather than `if a=true`? Similarly for the other clauses.

Comment: Thank you. Didnt know that i could write it like that.

Comment: Since the first three expressions between `in` and `end` have no side effects, those statements have no effect and that entire block is equivalent to `if d<120 then x+4.0 else x+0.0`. Is it your intention to modify the value of `x` in those clauses? It seems to be -- but then you are thinking imperatively rather than functionally. Also -- what do you even mean by "get the output as `x`"?

Comment: I want to get the value for x. For Example if i call the function calc(false,false,true,119) =>  7.0.

Comment: You need to have several sequential `val` bindings in the `let` part (with no semicolons needed) and then a single expression in the `in` part.

Comment: Okey... but how can i solve this problem? Why i cant write more then one if in one function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there is no problem with having multiple `if` expressions in a single function definition. For example, the following is unproblematic:

```
fun sign x = if x < 0  then ~1
            else if x = 0 then 0
            else 1;
```

Note that `if ... then ... else` is an expression which yields a value, not a control structure. You have several independent `if` expressions in that `in` block, separated by semicolons. When you have several expressions in such an `in` block, they are evaluated sequentially, with the result of the last expression being the overall value of that block. This only makes sense when the earlier expressions have side effects (e.g. printing something to the terminal or modifying the store using a `ref` variable). In your cases, your expressions have no side effects and you are simply discarding the values (except the very last one).

You seem to want to have a series of val bindings, where the later ones depend on the earlier ones. This can be done, but it would need to be in the `let` part of the construct rather than in the `in` part. Something like:

```
fun calc(a:bool, b:bool, c:bool, d:int) = 
let
    val x = 0.0
    val x = if a then x+1.0 else x
    val x = if b then x+2.0 else x
    val x = if c then x+3.0 else x
in
    if d<120 then x+4.0 else x
end
```

For example:

```
- calc(false,false,true,119);
val it = 7.0 : real
```

You can do this more directly by writing a helper function:

```
fun f(a,x) = if a then x else 0.0;
```

And then:

```
fun calc(a,b,c,d) =  
let
   val x = f(a,1.0) + f(b,2.0) + f(c,3.0)
in
   if d < 120 then x + 4.0 else x
end
```

Comment: "`if ... then ... else ...` is a function which returns a value, not a control structure" -- It is unlike functions in the sense that its "operands" only get evaluated based on the condition; functions do get their arguments evaluated (strict evaluation). I think it is more precise to say: `if ...` is an *expression*, not a *statement*.