# Is there a way to put two actions as a result of then in the if - else statement?

Tags: sml

I want to make two results in if~~then~~.
For example,

```
fun count (x,[]) = 0
| count (x,y::ys) =
val cnt = 0
if x mod y = 0 then **/ cnt+1 and count(x,y/2) /**
else count (x-y,ys)
```

If the if statement is true, as in `**/   /**`, is there a way to make it do two things?

Comment: What exactly is this function supposed to count? `count(x, y/2)` makes no sense, since the function's second argument is a list.

Comment: Also, that's not a statement but an expression.

Comment: Well, what I was trying to do was find out the number of cases where you can express 100 with 25 and 50 through the count function!
I'm trying to follow the advice from the other person below, but it's not going well. I think SML is too difficult.

Comment: The phrase "express 100 with 25 and 50" is still very vague. What exactly *are* the ways?

Comment: Wait a minute. I'll upload another post and show you a C program!

Comment: Attempting to translate a C program to SML is usually futile. Functional programming requires a different way of thinking. (You're finding it difficult not because it is more difficult, but because it's less familiar.)

Comment: Oh, that's right! I'm trying to change my mind, but there's no place to teach in Korean language, so I'm trying to understand English, so the stage is going very slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to make two results in if~~then~~ *[...]*

You can make a function that returns two results by using a tuple, e.g.:

```ml
(* Calculate the two solutions of a 2nd degree polynomial *)
fun poly (a, b, c) =
    let val d = b*b - 4.0*a*c
        val sqrt_d = Math.sqrt d
    in ( (~b + sqrt_d) / (2.0*a), (~b - sqrt_d) / (2.0*a) )
    end
```

And you can also deliver two different results depending on some criterion, e.g.:

```ml
fun poly (a, b, c) =
    let val d = b*b - 4.0*a*c
        val sqrt_d = Math.sqrt d
        val root_1 = (~b + sqrt_d) / (2.0*a)
        val root_2 = (~b - sqrt_d) / (2.0*a)
    in
      if root_1 > root_2
      then (root_1, root_2)
      else (root_2, root_1)
    end
```

But if you need for a function to return one result in one situation, and two results in another situation, you need to wrap the result in a return type that can hold *either* one *or* two values, e.g.:

```ml
datatype ('a, 'b) one_or_two = One of 'a | Two of 'a * 'b

datatype item = Apple | Lamp | Knife

val gen = Random.newgen ()
fun loot () =
    if Random.random gen > 0.90
    then Two (Lamp, Knife)
    else One Apple
```

You may also read the following StackOverflow Q&A: [Multiple if statemens in one Function in SML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47015392/multiple-if-statemens-in-one-function-in-sm)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll apply the function you mentioned and practice it!